# How can I share data between two winform applications?

Tags: vb.net, architecture

I have two VB projects in one VS2010 solution.  The first program brings in about 60 integers every few seconds from my PC's serial port.  The second program, published via Click-Once and running on my customer's PC, needs to see that new data every two to five seconds.

Is there a simple and reliable way to accomplish this, staying with VB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324) to establish a contract between producer and consumer of the data, implement it ant voila!

[WCF Example.](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2007/04/20/wcf-simple-example.aspx)

Note: Basics steps to get started:

- Define your contract (that is, define the interface you'll use to communicate)
- Generate the WCF proxy
- Implement the server side (the one that hosts the WCF service)
- Implement the client side (the one that connects and consumes the WCF service)

Comment: I've been reading about WCF for 40 minutes and haven't come close to understanding all that is involved.  Are you sure this is the simplest approach?  We're only talking about moving a bunch of integers from one program to another.

Comment: It's simple, but not trivial. I've posted a link to an example (google for WCF example and you'll find tons of examples). Anyway moving data between applications (specially over network) is not such a simple thing as you might think :) WCF makes it as simple as it gets

Comment: Jorge - Thanks for the example post and your added comments.  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @John, there are simpler ways, but those methods get more complicated as your project grows.  Something such as WCF is generally the way to go, to save your sanity in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (and fastest) Just write them in a txt (or XML is better) file from the first application and read them from the other
Fast and easy

Answer (score 0):

Look into Memory-Mapped files in .net 4.